# OpenCV: cv2.trianulatePoints возвращает странный результат

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, numpy

Приветствую всех. Мне нужно восстановить пространственные координаты нескольких точек по двум фотографиям, точки выбираются вручную. Для проверки решил использовать объект с известной геометрией - небольшую картонную коробку.
Мои действия:

1. Собираю данные. Доска закреплена на столе, камера закреплена на штативе. С одного ракурса делаю снимок доски, ставлю коробку, делаю ещё один кадр. Для второго ракурса повторяю то же самое (нет возможности сделать снимок сразу с двух камер). Далее делаю ещё около 10 снимков одной доски.
2. Калибрую камеру с помощью cv2.calibrateCamera, сохраняю матрицу внутренних параметров и матрицы внешних параметров для нужных мне видов в файл. Ошибка (reprojection error) получается около 0,071.

   ```
   ret, mtx, dist, r_vecs, t_vecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(obj_points, img_points, shape, None, None)  
   extr = []
   # Если калибровка прошла успешно
   if ret:
       for view in views:
           # Преобразование Родрига превратит вектор в матрицу поворота
           matrix, jacobian = cv2.Rodrigues(r_vecs[view], None, None)
           # Приписываем столбец к нашей матрице
           extr.append(np.hstack((matrix, t_vecs[view])))
   ```
3. Пытаюсь восстановить координаты с помощью c2.triangulatePoints

Тут начинаются проблемы. Функция triangulatePoints возвращает странный результат:[image: Содержимое homogeneous через отладчик]
Разные точки имеют одинаковые координаты, повторяясь через одну, для каких-то, как видно на скриншоте, получаются нули там, где их быть не должно.

```
# Читаем матрицы из файла
intrinsic = np.fromfile('result/intrinsic.txt', dtype=np.float32, count=-1, sep=' ').reshape(3, 3)
l_ext = np.fromfile('result/extrinsic0.txt', dtype=np.float32, count=-1, sep=' ').reshape(3, 4)
r_ext = np.fromfile('result/extrinsic1.txt', dtype=np.float32, count=-1, sep=' ').reshape(3, 4)
# Получаем матрицы проекций
l_proj = intrinsic.dot(l_ext)
r_proj = intrinsic.dot(r_ext)
# Координаты соответствующих точек на левом и правом снимках
l_points = np.array([(240, 612), (606, 709), (1074, 455), (265, 793), (618, 900), (1077, 612)])
r_points = np.array([(448, 573), (726, 701), (1323, 486), (465, 747), (733, 891), (1318, 648)])
# Непосредственно восстановление
homogeneous = cv2.triangulatePoints(l_proj, r_proj, l_points.T, r_points.T)
reconstructed = cv2.convertPointsFromHomogeneous(homogeneous.T)
```

Использую OpenCV 3.3.1 вместе с Python 3.6.3 в составе Anaconda под Windows.